# Firefox 27.0.1 Address Bar Completion Pop-up Text Blank

Tags: unity, firefox, display

I can't seem to catch a screenshot, but the drop-down menu that appears when you're typing into the address bar with suggestions seems to be broken. The icons on the left-hand side of each suggestion appear, and the rows are highlighted when I hover over, but there's no text at all. Might be a Firefox bug, might have to do with the display manager; I'm not sure.

Comment: I confirm that using the "Restart with Add-ons Disabled" menu option fixes the problem. Going to try to disable add-ons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the Delicious Bookmarks add-on seems to have fixed the issue. I haven't been using delicious recently, so disabling is fine for now. I'll look for an update to the add-on.